# aws.config.update() not updating the AWS credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

I'm fairly new to using AWS and aws-cli. I'm trying to update a dynamo DB table by writing a node script using aws-SDK.I have created a shared credential file that has all the credentials from two of my aws accounts and now I'm having trouble configuring the relevant credentials to the script that I'm trying to run to update the Db. Therefore I used aws.config.update() method to update the configurations but it still doesn't do the job , hence I get the "ResourceNotFoundException" when I run the code. Here's my code.

```js
const aws = require("aws-sdk");

aws.config.update({
  accessKeyId: "xxxxxxxx",
  accessSecretKey: "xxxx",
  region: "ap-south-1",
});
const docClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
async function update() {
  try {

    var params = {
   
      TableName: "employee",
      Key: {
      
        ID: "1",
      },
      UpdateExpression: "set EmployeeName =:fullName",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":fullName": "test 3",
      },
    };
    var result = docClient.update(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else console.log(data);
    });
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    
    console.error(error);
  }
}
update();
```

Please help me find a solution set up the relevant configurations and the reason behind aws.config.update() not working for me .

Comment: Is this your unmodified code? `aws.config.update()` would **not** work if called *after* `new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()` but should have worked as intended if used *before* that, as shown here.

Comment: @ Michael - sqlbot   Yes . This is my unmodified code.

Comment: Assuming you're running the latest SDK, I can't readily explain this.  Be sure to add `"use strict";` at the top of the file to help catch some subtle typos.  I don't see any here but that's still considered best practice as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you , I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this way

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk"

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: config.region, accessKeyId: config.accessKeyId, secretAccessKey: config.secretAccessKey });
```

If I'm not mistaken, You will get the "ResourceNotFoundException" error, when your DynamoDB table did not exist. Check your AWS credentials, please.

Comment: My credentials were right. Trying this way worked. It would be lovely if you could please clarify the difference between the 2 methods so that I can understand why aws.config.update() didn't work here.

Comment: The more information you can find [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-region.html). And mark the answer as useful if it is

Comment: @CyberEternal that link doesn't seem to offer any explanation of why `aws.config.update()` doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Actually. this way should work too. But in my experience, the second way of configuring works without issues.